# How to add multiple data attributes in ionic 3 select option

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to add attributes in select option,
I have json like-

```
this.userlists = { "id":1 "name":"John", "age":31 };

<ion-select [(ngModel)]="userdtl">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let ul of userlists" value="{{ul.id}}">{{ul.name}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

How to add "**age**" attributes in option, because i have need user id and age also when submit form

Comment: I don't understand the qurstion. Are you trying to create  heterogeneous select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
...
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="userdtl">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let ul of userlists" value="{{ul}}">{{ul.name}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
...
</form>
```

in your ts-fie

```
submitForm(){

  [do something whit this.userdtl] //it contains the complete record including age because value is set to ul
}
```

Comment: It's wrong, because when i use like this all options select

Comment: <ion-option *ngFor="let ul of userlists" [value]="ul">{{ul.name}}</ion-option>     //this is working

Answer (score 0):

I hope I get you right. You can add the age this way:

```
<ion-option *ngFor="let ul of userlists" value="{{ul.id}}">{{ul.name}} {{ul.age}}</ion-option>
```